# How to pass setInterval() into a Javascript class method?

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop

I'm trying to make a photo slide show. I'm trying to set a timer to run every 5 seconds with `setInterval()`, I'm practicing classes and don't know how would I incorporate it within the class.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.js-gallery');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__item');
Array.from(list);

class Gallery {
  constructor(slideshow) {
    this.slideshow = slideshow;
    this.slideCount = list.length;
    this.items = items[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.currentSlide = 1;
  }

  transitionSlide() {
    if (this.currentSlide < this.slideCount) {
      list.style.transform = `translateX(-${this.currentSlide * this.items}px)`;
      this.currentSlide += 1;
    } else {
      list.style.transform = `translateX(0)`;
      this.currentSlide = 1;
    }
  }

  // Trying to make a method with setInterval() so that the slide runs every 5 seconds.
  

}

const pics = new Gallery(list);
```

```css
.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}


.gallery-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery__item {
  list-style: none;
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Gallery of Real Cool JS3 Images</h1>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <ul class="gallery js-gallery">
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=1062')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=837')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=1025')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=237')"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want `transitionSlide` to be executed every 5 seconds correct?

Comment: Yes I want transitionSlide to be executed every 5 seconds.

Comment: `setInterval(this.transitionSlide.bind(this), 5000);`

Comment: Or `setInterval(() => this.transitionSlide(), 5000);`

Comment: Alright, give me a moment posting an answer as there might be a couple of other issues in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working snippet below. I've made it so that it transitions every 0.5 seconds just so that you can see it faster. If you want it at 5 seconds, change the interval to 5000 instead of 500.

In general, setInterval doesn't work any differently in a class than outside it. You just have to be mindful of `this` binding (i.e. if you did `setInterval(this.transitionSlide, 5000)`, this wouldn't work as `this` would lose scope, hence the `.bind(this)`)

Key things to note:

1. You want to track the setInterval's return value, which is an interval ID. This will let you stop the interval from constantly happening.
2. We now have 2 functions - startSlideshow and stopSlideshow and when you instantiate a new `Gallery`, you should use `.startSlideshow()` on the instance variable whenever you want it to start.
3. You were using `list.length` for the slideCount when you needed to use `items.length` since that's what was tracking the individual slides.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.js-gallery');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__item'); // Use this for slide count, not list
Array.from(list); // Doesn't do anything

class Gallery {
  constructor(slideshow) {
    this.slideshow = slideshow;
    this.slideCount = items.length;
    this.items = items[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.currentSlide = 1;
    this.slideTransitionInterval = null;
  }

  transitionSlide() {
    console.log('invoked');
    if (this.currentSlide < this.slideCount) {
      list.style.transform = `translateX(-${this.currentSlide * this.items}px)`;
      this.currentSlide += 1;
    } else {
      this.stopSlideshow();
      list.style.transform = `translateX(0)`;
      this.currentSlide = 1;
    }
  }

  // Trying to make a method with setInterval() so that the slide runs every 5 seconds.
  startSlideshow() {
    this.stopSlideshow();
    this.slideTransitionInterval = setInterval(this.transitionSlide.bind(this), 500);
  }
  
  stopSlideshow() {
    if (this.slideTransitionInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.slideTransitionInterval);
    }
  }

}

const pics = new Gallery(list);
pics.startSlideshow();
```

```css
.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}


.gallery-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery__item {
  list-style: none;
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Gallery of Real Cool JS3 Images</h1>
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <ul class="gallery js-gallery">
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=1062')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=837')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=1025')"></li>
      <li class="gallery__item js-gallery-item" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/650/?image=237')"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the detailed information you provided, will study the key notes.

Comment: *If you want it at 5 seconds, change the interval to 5000 instead of 500.* =>  Oh, so close! ... Parameterize!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.startInterval(); // start interval in your constructor
    }
    
    startInterval() {
        const myInterval = setInterval(this.transitionSlide, 5000);
    }
    
    transitionSlide() {
        // ... logic for slideshow
        console.log("Slideshow transitioned.");
    }
}

const cls = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Doesn't do slide the photos, and there's no errors though.

Comment: I was just showing you the logic for it that you could implement on your own :) But it seems like you got another working answer so go with that.